# Update chart in Chart js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

```
import Chart from "chart.js"

let AnalyticsChart = {

  buildChart() {
    let ctx = document.getElementById("analyticsChart");
    let labels = ["sent", "delivered", "undelivered", "clicks"];

    let total_sent = parseInt(document.getElementById("total-sent").dataset.totalSent);
    let delivered = parseInt(document.getElementById("deilvered-count").dataset.deliveredCount);
    let undelivered = parseInt(document.getElementById("undelivered-count").dataset.undeliveredCount);
    let clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById("total-clicks").dataset.totalClicks);
    let counts = [total_sent, delivered, undelivered, clicks]
    let chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
          data: counts,
          backgroundColor: [

            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.5)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.5)',
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.5)'
          ]
        }] 
      },
      options: {

      }
    });

  },

  update(){

  }
}


export default AnalyticsChart
```

in this code I want to add update function to update chart.
I want to pass chart variable to update function how can I do this?

like this

```
update(chart) {
    let total_sent = parseInt(document.getElementById("total-sent").dataset.totalSent);
    let delivered = parseInt(document.getElementById("deilvered-count").dataset.deliveredCount);
    let undelivered = parseInt(document.getElementById("undelivered-count").dataset.undeliveredCount);
    let clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById("total-clicks").dataset.totalClicks);
    let counts = [total_sent, delivered, undelivered, clicks]

    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(counts) # How can I put individual counts value?
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

My questions 
1. How can I pass chart variable in buildChart() to update function as parameter.
2. how can I put individual counts element in dataset.data.push(counts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar the way of your implement.
But it seems like java, so you need member variable, and access them using `this` from each function.

```
let AnalyticsChart = {
    chart: null,
    buildChart() {
        /** omit **/
        this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    ~
    update() {
        /** omit **/
        this.chart.update();
```

I'm sorry I don't quite understand the question2.
Do you want to push the data, rather than update? If so, you can't do it just prepare the value. (I mean, you need labels, background...)
If you just want to update the chart, that is a piece of cake

```
this.chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
    dataset.data = counts;
});
```

Remember, you have one datasets.
If datasets is not dynamically, I think there's no need to loop.

```
this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = counts;
```